# Dont add duplicate values MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose query :

```
let employeeData = [];
if (employees) {
  employeeData = employees.map((employee) => ({ name: employee.name }));
}

await Employee.insertMany(employeeData);
```

This works but adds a lot of duplicate values. I only want to insert unique values. How do i do this?

Comment: Set the `name` index as unique, job done :)

Comment: @JeremyThille wont this just stop the process and return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the `name` index as unique

   `db.employees.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )`
2. Use insertMany with the `ordered:false` option, which won't stop the insertion if there are duplicates

   `await Employee.insertMany(employeeData, { ordered : false });`